# Twitter Bootstrap button_to switch to icon on mobile

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that contains buttons in one of the cells. The buttons are words but I want to make the words toggle to simple icons on mobile and when resized smaller. My current code looks like this for the buttons.

In my view I have:

```
<td width="17.5%"><%= which_button(ra) %></td>
```

In my helper file I have

```
def which_button(ra)
  if ra.tenant_approved == false
    button_to "Approve?", { controller: "tenants/reportapprovals", id: ra.id, action: "update" }, method: :patch, class: "btn-default btn-xs", data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to give #{ra.manager_company} access to your report?" }
  else
....
end
```

How can I toggle the "Approve?" to a thumbs up icon when a smaller screen?

Comment: Are you sure you choose right tags?

Comment: @Banzay What do you mean right tags?

Comment: I mean that tags `html`, `css`, `twitter-bootstrap`. You provided the code that's not like neither html nor css.

Comment: @Banzay Oh, I see what you mean. I added the line of code from my view but my view is using logic from a helper. I just need to use some sort of toggle I assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to toggle words/images depending on screen size, you could use twitter-bootstrap's [Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to show/hide content depending on media query.

[image]

E.g.:

```
<h1 class="visible-xs">Only visible on xtra-small screen</h1>
<h1 class="visible-sm">Only visible on small screen</h1>    
<h1 class="visible-md">Only visible on medium screen</h1>    
<h1 class="visible-lg">Only visible on large screen</h1>
```

In your case I'd guess that would be something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="visible-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-xs">
    Text here only visible when bigger then xs
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! But how do you use these classes if you want to show words in anything larger than xs but only an icon if in xs? I tried ````button_to <i class="hidden-xs">"Approve?"</i><i class="visible-xs-block glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i>, { controller: "tenants/reportapprovals", id: ra.id, action: "update" }, method: :patch, class: "btn-default btn-xs", data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to give #{ra.manager_company} access to your report?" }````